# How can I write a zip file using InputStream (uploaded file) in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, outputstream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I want to create a zip file and write it the data from InputStream and save it in a specified folder in java.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating zip archive in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773778/creating-zip-archive-in-java)

Comment: follow this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/