# saving base64 decoded string into a zip file

Tags: java, string, zip, base64, decode

I am trying to save a base64 decoded string into a zip file using the mentioned code:

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/home/wemohamm/Desktop/test.zip")));
out.write(decodedString);
out.close();
```

Here `decodedString` contains base64 decoded string and I can output it.
I am running the code in rhel6 with Java 1.6. When I try to open the zip, it says error occurred while opening file.

The same code if I use with Windows 7 Java 1.6 with path `c:\\test\test.zip` is working fine.

Is the zip not getting saved correctly in rhel6 or if there is any code modifications I need to do?

Comment: why dont you create a correct zip file with java using ZipEntry?

Comment: The object decodedString is actually a base64 decoded string. And I have no idea how to save it as zip. By the way above works fine in windows.If something is wrong or to be modified, Please share it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773778/creating-zip-archive-in-java

Comment: you dont create a zip archive but a file and name it .zip
 use @Andrew s link.

Comment: Actually here decodedSting is a zip file stream. Why zip an already zipped stream.

Comment: to create a correct zip archive

Comment: A "Base64 decoded string", what is that exactly? Can you show how you do the decoding? Note that a `String` is not suitable for storing arbitrary bytes. Store bytes in a `byte[]` and not in a `String`.

Comment: I have a webservice sending a zip file in base64 encoded format in one of the xml tags. I am extracting it from the tags decoding it and then storing it in string named decodedString.

Comment: You are confusing us with `decodedString`.  Can you please show more clearly what it is?  Is it really a string?  Or is it actually a byte array that is actually nothing more than a zip file in disguise?

Comment: Pardon me for confusing ..Yes its a byte arrary.NodeList filee = element.getElementsByTagName("dp:file");
       line = (Element) filee.item(0);
       System.out.println("file: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
       String fileContent=getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
       
       byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(fileContent.getBytes()) ;
       
       String decodedString = new String(byteArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a string from your byte array (`String decodedString = new String(byteArray);`), to then use an `OutputStreamWriter` to write the string, because then you are running the risk of introducing encoding issues that are platform dependent.

Just use `FileOutputStream` to write out the byte array (`byte[] byteArray`) directly to file.

Something like:

```
try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/wemohamm/Desktop/test.zip"), 4096)) {
    out.write(byteArray);
}
```

Actually, the above requires java 1.7+, because of the new `try-with-resources` statement.

For Java 1.6, you can do this:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/wemohamm/Desktop/test.zip"), 4096);
    out.write(byteArray);
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using jre 1.6, eclipse points out error and suggests changing to jre1.7 which I cant do, since this code is to run on jre 1.6

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. You are writing to a ordinary file without packing the content. Use the java zip library with `ZipOutputStream`, `ZipEntry` and so on.